# Redirect with the same form/request values (POST)

Tags: php, http

Is it possible to redirect to another page, say add.php with the request that were sent to the original page.

Say I have a file: form.html that has a post form
Now I submit this to form.php.

I want form.php to redirect the request to add.php so that add receives the same POST parameteres as form.php

this is done so that form.php can analyze a hidden field called action and depending on its value redirect to add.php or edit.php . I know this can be done in javascript by changing the form.action attribute. I am wondering if it is possible on server side

Comment: Why don't you have a single file instead? That can both handle editing and adding

Comment: Why not just use an `include()`/`require()`? Submit to the form.php and then include the relevant script depending on the requested action.

Comment: Well, this is the requirement I have for the application.

Comment: If Add and edit are related to the same model eg add edit page/cms then your be better off putting it in a single controller/page, imo things like this should be kept together with an blank `action=""` determine if its edit or add by the url structure eg `example.com/page/add` or `example.com/page/edit/id`

Comment: I knw, but the actual requirement is to forward to a different domain: So the page is on example.com and it will redirect to example2.com or example3.com; So this is an external script doing the work.

Its a little crazy, but that's the requirement I have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply require_once inside a switch or if block.
If you really need *actual* redirection (i.e. you want the user to *know* where they were redirected to), you may need to send a 'fake' intermediate page, with an auto-submitting (via javascript) form full of hidden inputs.

The reason is right in [the HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> If the 302 status code is received in response to a request other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might change the conditions under which the request was issued.

Comment: So if I do a 302 redirect, it will confirm with the user and then forward the values

Comment: That's not exactly reliable... that's just the intention of the spec authors... You only have one guarantee (via the "MUST NOT" verbiage), it will *not* automatically re-submit your form.

Comment: The reliable way (if require will not work), is also mentioned in my answer: *send a reply which is a self-submitting form*. In my experience, sometime around 2-4 years ago we all started deciding it was relatively safe to assume that our users had javascript.

Comment: yes ofc, but i just wanted to know if it could be done on server side.  I have an action changing javascript that i use to determine which action it should send to. I was just wondering if there was a serverside failsafe

Answer (score 1):

In your form.php declare hidden fields for each form value in form.html and assign the value from the post data

```
//form.php
<form name="newform" action="add.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="field1" value="<?php echo(@$_POST['field1']); ?>" />
    ... declare other hidden fields like above
    ... field1 represent post value from the previous page form.html

</form>

<?php
    if(editConditionSatisfied)
    {
       echo '
          <script type="text/javascript">
             document.forms["newform"].action = "edit.php";
             document.forms["newform"].submit();
          </script>
       ';
    }
    else
    {
       echo '
          <script type="text/javascript">
             document.forms["newform"].action = "add.php";
             document.forms["newform"].submit();
          </script>
       ';
    }
?>
```

You can make sure all conditions and processes take place before writing the script out. The script does not take effect until you write them out and it resubmit your data to where you want

Hope that helps

Comment: as I said, I kniow the javascript solution. I was just wondering if there is a server side failsafe

Comment: No Problem. I posted because of your comment "_okay thanks. so now way of reliably doing it_"

Answer (score 0):

You could also use cURL to make the POST request to edit.php or add.php from form.php depending upon your logic.

form.php

```
$value1 = $_POST["field1"];
//assuming your field names are field1 etc..
//assign variables for all fields.

$body = "field1=".value1."&field2=".value2;
//etc for all field/value pairs
//to transmit same names to edit.php or add.php

//pseudo code for condition based on $_POST["action"]
if(condition TRUE for add.php){
    $url = "example2.com/add.php";
} elseif((condition TRUE for edit.php){
     $url = "example3.com/edit.php";
}

if(isset($url)){     //most probably true, but just for safe-guard
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);            //we are making POST request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);  //setting the POST fields
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}

//do something based on $response
//like doing a simple header redirect to $url
```

Now, your add.php or edit.php will see exactly like they are getting a POST form request.

Make both of them send a response in 200 (success) or 404 (failed) so that you could capture it in $response and continue as required.

Note that I assume user inputs are already sanitized. (Which you should on the top of form.php, before assigning anything to $value1)